# Cómo puedo reiniciar un timer?

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiento código que lo que hace es crear un timer en el que se hace una cuenta regresiva desde el 10, pero necesito hacer que cada vez que se oprima un botón el tiempo vuelva a ser 10 segundos y el timer vuelva a tener una cuenta regresiva. Mejor dicho, el timer reinicia.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tiempo--;
        timer1.Start();
        label3.Text = Convert.ToString(tiempo);
        if (tiempo == 0)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("El tiempo se ha agotado.");
        }
    }
```

Algunas Sugerencias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente, al hacer click en el botón, tienes que detener el timer y volver a iniciarlo.
Pero cuidado debes de sacar el `timer1.Start()` del timer_tick porque por cada segundo estás volviendo a iniciar el timer.

```
tiempo = 10;
timer1.Stop();
timer1.Start();
```

Comment: y tiempo = 10 que hace?